# HAML with forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this form:

```
= simple_form_for :login, url: sessions_path, method: :post, role: "form", class: "form-horizontal" do |f|
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: "Stay connected"
  = f.submit "Login", class: "btn btn-primary"
  = link_to 'Forgot Password?', new_password_reset_path
```

After a bit of Bootstrap styling:

```
.panel.panel-primary
  .panel-heading
    %p
      the login form
  .panel-body
    = simple_form_for :login, url: sessions_path, method: :post, role: "form", class: "form-horizontal" do |f|
      = f.input :email
      = f.input :password
      = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: "Stay connected"
  .panel-footer
    = f.submit "Login", class: "btn btn-primary"
    = link_to 'Forgot Password?', new_password_reset_path
```

I get `undefined variable or method f`, what should be done to get it working? I tried nesting the `.panel-footer` inside the form, it works but I didn't get the proper styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now, the submit button is out of your form block. So you can wrap all the things into the form block like the following.

```
     = simple_form_for :login, url: sessions_path, method: :post, role: "form", class: "form-horizontal" do |f|    
      .panel.panel-primary
          .panel-heading
            %p
              the login form
          .panel-body
            = f.input :email
            = f.input :password
            = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: "Stay connected"
          .panel-footer
            = f.submit "Login", class: "btn btn-primary"
            = link_to 'Forgot Password?', new_password_reset_path
```

Comment: You have to put the panelS (plural) in the form, that makes complete sense!  Thank You for posting this Answer, I had this exact issue and it was driving me nuts.  Anytime I tried to put the submit button into the panel-footer the f. on the form acted like it lost connection to the form itself.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH @Bachan Smruty  !!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, that is completely dependent on how your css looks like, but what you could do is something like

```
= simple_form_for :login, url: sessions_path, method: :post, role: "form", class: "form-horizontal" do |f|
  .panel-body
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :password
    = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: "Stay connected"
  .panel-footer
    = f.submit "Login", class: "btn btn-primary"
    = link_to 'Forgot Password?', new_password_reset_path
```

But it is not an issue with HAML, with erb you would have the same exception